# Couchdb list api - can't seem to return plain/text

Tags: couchdb

I am trying to return text/plain from a couchdb list but it is not working. The content is returned correctly but the content type seems to be forced to application/json.

Code snippet is

```
              start({ "headers" : {"Content-type" : "text/plain"}});
              send("Nono, you can't do this");
```

Before this code there is one getRow invoked. If I remove that the text/plain content type is returned as expected.

Not sure what is going wrong here and I can't really avoid the getRow as the result of that determines the content type to return.

Any guidance warmly welcomed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CouchDB starts the response (including sending the default Content-Type header) when you first call getRow(), so what you are seeing is expected behaviour.

Submit a ticket to our JIRA (http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB), though, and perhaps it can be delayed, allowing the useful effect you are attempting.